# Sort mixed list using subtype specific behaviour Kotlin

Tags: class, sorting, kotlin, comparator

I have a list of items which share a base class but are very different, and would like to sort them first by their class, then by a comparator specific to that class.

Eg `SubtypeA` should be sorted by the property `foo` which is specific to that class, while `SubTypeB` should be sorted by the properties `bar1` then `bar2` which are specific to that class, and I need to sort lists containing both.

The actual order of the sort is unimportant, just that it is consistent within a runtime so that two lists of these objects can be checked for equality by first sorting them.

(Up until this point I have just used a lazy property that adds the object to a set and checks its index, thus giving equal objects the same sortkey, but this cache is growing to ludicrous sizes that make things very slow)

How can I group these objects by their class to then use a class specific comparator?

Comment: So when you sort types of SubTypeA and SubTypeB are they sorted using foo or bar1 and bar2, or something else?

Comment: @mattfreake I am not sure I understand your question. Are you asking what order the classes should be in? If that is the question, it really doesn't matter, I was thinking of using the hashcode of the class or something. Edit: To be clear, if a solution required ordering them in some other way, that would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that might serve your needs.

We supply separate comparator for all subtypes, and simply group all by type and sort each group with it's own comparator, after that simply sort groups by their class name and flatten elements from each group in consecutive manner.

Here is code example demonstrating it.

- added utility function `sortedUsing` to perform this sorting
- added an utility type `TypeComparator` just to have more convenient way to pass type safe Class + Comparator

```
fun <T : Any> List<T>.sortedUsing(
        vararg typeComparators: TypeComparator<out T>
): List<T> {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun <R : T> TypeComparator<R>.sort(list: List<T>): List<R> = (list as List<R>).sortedWith(comparator)

    val comparators = typeComparators.associateBy { it.type }
    return groupBy { it::class }
            .mapValues { (klass, list) ->
                val typeComparator = comparators[klass]
                        ?: typeComparators.firstOrNull { klass.isSubclassOf(it.type) }
                        ?: list.firstOrNull()?.tryMakeComparator()
                        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Missing comparator for type: $klass")
                typeComparator.sort(list)
            }
            .map { it }
            .sortedBy { it.key.qualifiedName }
            .flatMap { it.value }
}

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
private fun <T : Any> T.tryMakeComparator(): TypeComparator<T>? {
    if (this !is Comparable<*>) {
        return null
    }
    return TypeComparator(this::class as KClass<T>, Comparator { o1, o2 ->
        val c1 = o1 as Comparable<Comparable<T>>
        val c2 = o2 as Comparable<T>
        c1.compareTo(c2)
    })
}

data class TypeComparator<T : Any>(
        val type: KClass<T>,
        val comparator: Comparator<T>
)
```

You could also supply comparator for type if you'd like to, because default in snippet above is to order typed groups by class full name.

With some better way of accumulating elements of some type, you could get rid of unchecked list cast.

Usage example:

```
open class Base

data class SubtypeA(
        val foo: Int
) : Base()

data class SubtypeB(
        val bar1: String,
        val bar2: String
) : Base()

fun main() {
    val list = listOf(
            SubtypeA(5),
            SubtypeB("foo", "x"),
            SubtypeA(42),
            SubtypeA(2),
            SubtypeB("bar", "y"),
            SubtypeB("bar", "x")
    )
    val sorted = list.sortedUsing(
            TypeComparator(SubtypeA::class, Comparator.comparing { a: SubtypeA -> a.foo }),
            TypeComparator(SubtypeB::class, Comparator.comparing { b: SubtypeB -> b.bar1 }.thenComparing { b: SubtypeB -> b.bar2 })
    )
    sorted.forEach { println(it) }
    // prints:
    //   SubtypeA(foo=2)
    //   SubtypeA(foo=5)
    //   SubtypeA(foo=42)
    //   SubtypeB(bar1=bar, bar2=x)
    //   SubtypeB(bar1=bar, bar2=y)
    //   SubtypeB(bar1=foo, bar2=x)

}
```

Comment: This is great thank you. However, two questions:
This is for a multi-platform project, so will this work replacing `::class.java` with `::class` and `Class<T>` with `KClass<T>`?
Second, is it sensible to try to access a method of the class for the comparator object rather than having them as arguments?

Comment: Also if you want to handle Lists with nullable elements you can just add another extension like so 
`fun <T : Any> List<T?>.sortedNullableUsing(vararg typeComparators: 
 TypeComparator<out T>): List<T?> = (0 until count { it == null }).map { null } + filterNotNull().sortedUsing(*typeComparators)`